# Python set environment variable when creating venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, virtualenv, python-venv

In my project I use the built-in python virtual env (`python -m venv`).
To set environment variables I add multiple `export VAR1=VALUE1` to the end of the `venv/bin/activate`.
Obviously, when I delete the venv and create a new one, for example with the new python version all my env variables get lost.
So, is there a way to preserve them? May be it is possible to define env variables when creating the venv?

Comment: if you delete a file, but you want a backup, you could copy it. Or just use a text editor to copy the lines that export variable names, and put that in a different script. You're going to have to edit the new activate script, regardless.

Answer (score 6):

instead of adding to `activate`

```
export VAR1=VALUE1
```

consider writing them into their own file:

**~/setupenv.sh**:

```
export VAR1=VALUE1
```

and add the following to `activate`

```
source ~/setupenv.sh
```

However, personally, I would not do that.  I would instead define a bash function to do it:

```
myownactivate(){
  source <path_to_activate>
  export VAR1=VALUE1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Essentially, you have to create a simple `.env` file that containsyour variables and values and it will load them when you run your application.

You can access them by `os.getenv('VAR1')`

Comment: I would give the same advice for dotenv. But it is not complete without stating, that the application itself is then responsible for loading the env file. That is not exactly what was asked by the OP.

Comment: @VPfB `. .env` should be added to the end of the `venv/bin/activate`

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if you add `export VAR1=VALUE1` at the end of `$HOME/.bashrc`, can you still access the environment variable by calling `os.getenv()` ?